# Bot Framework doesn't have username if telegram profile doesn't have full name or username

Tags: botframework, telegram-bot

Messages delivered from Bot Framework don't have `name` property in `from` object if message was sent by user who doesn't have username and full name. For example if you delete first or last name from profile like that

[image: example of profile]

Here's example of json that I get for messages sent from user that only has first name (look at `from` object):

```
{
  "channelData": {
    "message": {
      "chat": {
        "all_members_are_administrators": true,
        "id": -219911672,
        "title": "jlarky-dev",
        "type": "group"
      },
      "date": 1493246056,
      "from": {
        "first_name": "Test",
        "id": 107390199
      },
      "message_id": 100,
      "text": "test"
    },
    "update_id": 66470785
  },
  "channelId": "telegram",
  "conversation": {
    "id": "-219911672",
    "isGroup": true,
    "name": "jlarky-dev"
  },
  "entities": [
    {
      "mentioned": {
        "id": "JLarkyTestBot",
        "name": "jlarky_test"
      },
      "text": "JLarkyTestBot",
      "type": "mention"
    }
  ],
  "from": {
    "id": "107390199"
  },
  "id": "KxBlE8JsLfg",
  "recipient": {
    "id": "JLarkyTestBot",
    "name": "jlarky_test"
  },
  "serviceUrl": "https://telegram.botframework.com",
  "text": "test",
  "timestamp": "2017-04-26T22:34:17.4109674Z",
  "type": "message"
}
```

Comment: I can't get the question. Anyhow, the name property comes to the `ChannelData` not in `from` object.

Comment: @OmG `from` object always has `id` and `name` except in case of some bugs like this one, `channelData` is channel (third party service) specific data that bot framework sends you.

Comment: So, you can get the `name` from `ChannelData` as you can see in the result.

Comment: use `channelData.from.first_name`

Comment: @NilsW yes, I think that is probably the best way to go here, still would be cool to see this bug fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Since @NilsW's comment I tested this again and it looks like `from.name` only exists when username of telegram profile was set (same can be looked up from `channelData.message.from.username`), so I guess it makes sense for it not to show username when username was not set :) and not having `last_name` part was not related here.